# How to use Google Drive API in a vue app?

Tags: vue.js, google-drive-api

There is a browser quickstart of Google API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js

The following tag is written in the sample code:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
```

Is using the above tag right way to use google api in a vue project? If so, where is the place to write the tag and functions such as handleClientLoad?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about but you can copy the script tag inside the `index.html` that is in the `public` folder created from vue-cli or vue ui. The needed functions can be writed inside the methods of your vue app and you can call them into the mounted hook if needed to init the gdrive api.